# why is my query not getting order the right way?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a query where I´m supposed to show the latest record of my users, I can filter by user or not. Here is an example of the data

```
id      fecha               no_emp
1326    2016-06-20 16:31:48 69976
1327    2016-06-20 16:31:38 69976
1328    2016-06-20 16:31:48 69976
1329    2016-06-21 17:22:37 69976
1330    2016-06-21 17:22:37 69976
1331    2016-06-27 13:06:22 69976
```

I´m supposed to get id 1331, and date 2016-06-27 13:06:22
But keep getting id 1326 and date 2016-06-20 16:31:48
if my query is:

```
SELECT id, fecha, no_emp
FROM of_direcciones
WHERE no_emp = '69976'
GROUP BY no_emp
order by ID DESC;
```

and I get id 13226 and date 2016-06-27 13:06:22 if my query is:

```
SELECT id, MAX(fecha), no_emp
FROM of_direcciones
WHERE no_emp= '69976'
GROUP BY no_emp;
```

What´s wrong in my query?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want the 'latest' record based on the date, then you should order by the date, not the id, you can use `limit 1` to return just the one record. Also, the returned id is arbitrary because you're not grouping by all non-aggregate fields from your select list. MySQL allows this, other databases would throw an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong with your query is that you are aggregating by `no_emp` and then choosing fields such as `id` which are not in the `group by` clause.  MySQL returns values from *indeterminate* rows in this case.  And, the *indeterminate* row might change, with each invocation of the query.

Here is a better way to get the latest record for a particular user:

```
select d.*
from of_direcciones d
where d.no_emp = '69976'
order by d.fecha desc
limit 1;
```

This can even take advantage of an index on `of_direcciones(no_emp, fecha)` for best performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should obtain the max(fecha) and the filter by this value and no_emp

```
 SELECT id,  fecha, no_emp
 FROM of_direcciones
 where  fecha =  (select max(fecha,) from of_direcciones  
                  WHERE no_emp= '69976')
 AND  no_emp= '69976';
```